# XGBoost on Python: Plot performance

Tags: classification, python, ggplot2

following the instructions from https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_intro.html

after building my model, i tried on Jupyter (using Mac OS X, Chrome browser)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.style.use('ggplot') 
xgb.plot_importance(bst) 
xgb.plot_tree(bst, num_trees=2) 
xgb.to_graphviz(bst, num_trees=2)
```

but i have some problems: the to_graphviz does return me a plot, but its too big, and i can't see it whole. Its cut on the right side

the first two commands (if i put a # in front of the last line) don't show any plot at all. is there something like a.show() missing ?

Instead i get the following output

> "matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x12f0ee7d0" (between <>)

can anyone help ? thank you

Comment: This would be great and on-topic if you asked it on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Do you only want the scaling fixed when running inside Jupyter, or Python in general?

Comment: See SO: [Purpose of `%matplotlib inline`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43027980/purpose-of-matplotlib-inline)

Answer (score 3):

When we do plotting in `jupyter`, we usually run the following magic command:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

to let it plot inside the web page.

Then you can run those plotting functions and see the image in place.